# call OnScrollListener for certain amount of visible item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I used a Circle Page Indicator as **ItemDecoration** at bottom of a recycler view with a **GridLayoutManager** & setting orientation as **Horizontal**. Currently, the indicator changes its position when the user moves an item left to right or vice versa. But I need to change the page indicator when total visible items (here 6) onscreen are offset when the user scrolled. So, the total number of indicators will decrease.

This picture tries to explain the problem.
[image]

It seems **RecyclerView.OnScrollListener** will be placed to handle the screen offset.

```
bindingView.listPaymentType.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            Log.i("listPaymentType","onScrolled")
        }

        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
            Log.i("listPaymentType","onScrollStateChanged")
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
        }
    })
```

Code I wrote for all stuffs here.

```
itemDecor = CirclePagerIndicatorDecoration()
    //bindingView.listPaymentType.addItemDecoration(itemDecor)
    viewModel.paymentList.observe(this, Observer {

        var layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 2,
                GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)

        bindingView.listPaymentType.removeItemDecorations()

        when {
            it.size == 4 -> {
                layoutManager.spanCount = 1
                bindingView.listPaymentType.addItemDecoration(itemDecor)
            }
            it.size > 4 -> {
                layoutManager.spanCount = 2
                bindingView.listPaymentType.addItemDecoration(itemDecor)
            }
            else -> {
                layoutManager.spanCount = 1
            }
        }

        bindingView.listPaymentType.layoutManager = layoutManager
        bindingView.listPaymentType.adapter = adapter
        adapter.update(it as ArrayList<PaymentMethod>)
        if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
            adapter.selectedItem(it[0])
        }
    })
```

CirclePagerIndicatorDecoration as follows:

```
class CirclePagerIndicatorDecoration : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

private val colorActive = 0xFF545455.toInt()
private val colorInactive = 0x33000000

/**
 * Height of the space the indicator takes up at the bottom of the view.
 */
private val mIndicatorHeight = (DP * 12).toInt()

/**
 * Indicator stroke width.
 */
private val mIndicatorStrokeWidth = DP * 4

/**
 * Indicator width.
 */
private val mIndicatorItemLength = DP * 2

/**
 * Padding between indicators.
 */
private val mIndicatorItemPadding = DP * 8

/**
 * Some more natural animation interpolation
 */
private val mInterpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()

private val mPaint = Paint()

init {
    mPaint.apply {
        strokeWidth = mIndicatorStrokeWidth
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        isAntiAlias = true
    }
}

override fun onDrawOver(c: Canvas, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
    super.onDrawOver(c, parent, state)

    val itemCount = parent.adapter?.itemCount?.div(COUNT_DIVIDER)?.toInt() ?: 0

    // center horizontally, calculate width and subtract half from center
    val totalLength = mIndicatorItemLength * itemCount
    val paddingBetweenItems = Math.max(0, itemCount - 1) * mIndicatorItemPadding
    val indicatorTotalWidth = totalLength + paddingBetweenItems
    val indicatorStartX = (parent.width - indicatorTotalWidth) / 2f

    // center vertically in the allotted space
    val indicatorPosY = parent.height - mIndicatorHeight / 2f

    drawInactiveIndicators(c, indicatorStartX, indicatorPosY, itemCount)

    // find active page (which should be highlighted)
    (parent.layoutManager as? LinearLayoutManager)?.let { layoutManager ->
        val activePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
        if (activePosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            return
        }

        // find offset of active page (if the user is scrolling)
        layoutManager.findViewByPosition(activePosition)?.let { activeChild ->
            val left = activeChild.left
            val width = activeChild.width
            // on swipe the active item will be positioned from [-width, 0]
            // interpolate offset for smooth animation
            val progress = mInterpolator.getInterpolation(left * -1 / width.toFloat())

            drawHighlights(c, indicatorStartX, indicatorPosY, activePosition, progress)
        }
    }
}

private fun drawInactiveIndicators(c: Canvas, indicatorStartX: Float, indicatorPosY: Float, itemCount: Int) {
    mPaint.color = colorInactive

    // width of item indicator including padding
    val itemWidth = mIndicatorItemLength + mIndicatorItemPadding

    var start = indicatorStartX
    for (i in 0 until itemCount) {
        c.drawCircle(start, indicatorPosY, mIndicatorItemLength / 2f, mPaint)
        start += itemWidth
    }
}

private fun drawHighlights(
        c: Canvas, indicatorStartX: Float, indicatorPosY: Float,
        highlightPosition: Int, progress: Float
) {
    mPaint.color = colorActive

    // width of item indicator including padding
    val itemWidth = mIndicatorItemLength + mIndicatorItemPadding
    val radius = mIndicatorItemLength / SCALE
    if (progress == 0f) {
        // no swipe, draw a normal indicator
        val highlightStart = indicatorStartX + itemWidth * highlightPosition

        c.drawCircle(highlightStart, indicatorPosY, radius, mPaint)

    } else {
        val highlightStart = indicatorStartX + itemWidth * highlightPosition
        // calculate partial highlight
        val partialLength = mIndicatorItemLength * progress + (mIndicatorItemPadding * progress)

        c.drawCircle(highlightStart + partialLength, indicatorPosY, radius, mPaint)
    }
}

override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
    super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)
    outRect.bottom = mIndicatorHeight
}

companion object {
    private val DP = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density
    private const val COUNT_DIVIDER: Float = 1.4f
    private const val SCALE: Float = 1.1f
}
```

}